# /usr/local/bin/git-credential-osxkeychain: Syntax error: "(" unexpected

Tags: git, github

I am getting the following error while using credential-osxkeychain

/usr/local/bin/git-credential-osxkeychain: Syntax error: "(" unexpected

Comment: That's an odd error for what should be a binary file.  Would you post the output of running `file /usr/local/bin/git-credential-osxkeychain`?

Comment: I am also getting the same error

Comment: I had the same issue following the instructions here (https://help.github.com/articles/caching-your-github-password-in-git/#platform-mac) when I made the mistake of following the Mac instructions on linux.

Comment: I had the same problem as I was using the Mac instructions on linux... (thanks @abitofcode). To remove the error I entered `git config --global --edit` and remove [helper] section. Then I used the github instructions for linux and saved my password without troubles :)